# On executing the code, else clause in main function is not working

Tags: python

I am trying to run this code

```
def main():
    month_name = [
         "January",
         "February",
         "March",
         "April",
         "May",
         "June",
         "July",
         "August",
         "September",
         "October",
         "November",
         "December"
         ]

    while True:
        try:
            date = dated(input("Date: "))
            month, day, year = date

            if int(day) <= 31:
                if 1<= int(month) <= 12:
                    month = month.zfill(2)
                    print(f"{year}-{month}-{day}")
                    break
                else:
                    if int(day) <= 31:
                        for i in range(len(month_name)):
                            if month_name[i] == month:
                                month = i+1
                                month = month.zfill(2)
                                print(f"{year}-{month}-{day}")
                                break
                            else:
                                return ValueError
        except ValueError:
            continue

def dated(s):
      if "/" in s:
        s = s.split("/")
        if len(s[1]) == 1:
            s[1] = s[1].zfill(2)
            return s
        else:
            return s

      else:
        s = s.split(" ")
        s[1] = s[1].replace(",","")
        if len(s[1])== 1:
            s[1] = s[1].zfill(2)
            return s
        else:
            return s





if __name__ == "__main__":
     main()
```

The purpose of this code is if an user provides input of date in mmddyyyy format specifically like 10/08/1991 or October 8, 1991 it will display the date in yyyymmdd format like 1991-10-08.
On executing this code for date format 10/08/1991, if the input is in range it works otherwise also the loop breaks but if the input is in second format October 8, 1991 the code is not working on trying to debug I found that for

```
while True:
        try:
            date = dated(input("Date: "))
            month, day, year = date

            if int(day) <= 31:
                if 1<= int(month) <= 12:
                    month = month.zfill(2)
                    print(f"{year}-{month}-{day}")
                    break
```

the code is running fine but after that for

```
else:
                    if int(day) <= 31:
                        for i in range(len(month_name)):
                            if month_name[i] == month:
                                month = i+1
                                month = month.zfill(2)
                                print(f"{year}-{month}-{day}")
                                break
                            else:
                                return ValueError
```

the code is not working.
if I input October 10, 1991 the code will jump straight to

```
except ValueError:
    continue
```

and I input 15/10/1991
the code breaks out.
The problem is coming only in if else part of main function, dated function is working perfectly fine.

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: So remove the try/except and see what the actual error is instead of hiding it.

Comment: If you typed `October 10, 1991`, then the call to the `dated` function will return `['October', '10', '1991']`, which means `month` will be `'October'`. You then try to do `if 1 <= int(month) <= 12:`, which in this case is the same as saying `if 1 <= int('October') <= 12:`. You are trying to convert the string `'October'` to an integer, which will raise a `ValueError` exception.

Comment: aside from the  comments above, there is a built-in module for handling dates:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html  , you should check this out before proceeding. it has lots of useful features that will benefit your code.

Comment: You are using as input `15/10/1991` and thus setting `month` to `15` according to  your method `dated()`. Try `print(dated("15/10/1991"))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a much cleaner way of achieving the same using the built-in `datetime` module.

```py
from datetime import datetime

def convert_date_to_yyyymmdd(date_str):
    try:
        # Try to parse the date in mm/dd/yyyy format
        date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%m/%d/%Y')
    except ValueError:
        try:
            # Try to parse the date in Month dd, yyyy format
            date_obj = datetime.strptime(date_str, '%B %d, %Y')
        except ValueError:
            # If both formats fail, raise an error
            raise ValueError("The date format is not recognized. Please use mm/dd/yyyy or Month dd, yyyy format.")
    
    # Convert the datetime object to the desired string format
    return date_obj.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Example usage:
date1 = "10/08/1991"
date2 = "October 8, 1991"

print(convert_date_to_yyyymmdd(date1))  # Output: 1991-10-08
print(convert_date_to_yyyymmdd(date2))  # Output: 1991-10-08
```

which returns:

```
1991-10-08
1991-10-08
```

Note that the `datetime` module has a multitude of other useful features too which will save you from reinventing the wheel.